# Simple "Hello World" in Angular2 is giving error

Tags: javascript, angular, components

Making first Angular2 program is giving some errors. Though, I feel I wrote correctly. Can, someone help me out?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.33.3/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.19.20/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.6/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.6/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.6/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.config({
        transpiler: 'typescript',
        typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true },
        packages: {'app': {defaultExtension: 'ts'}},
        map: { 'app': './angular2/src/app' }
      });

      System
          .import('hello_world_main')
          .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
  </head>
<body>
   <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

**hello_world_main.ts**

```
import {bootstrap} from "angular2/platform/browser"
import {MyHelloWorldClass} from "hello_world_app.component"
bootstrap(MyHelloWorldClass);
```

**hello_world_app.components.ts**

```
import {Component, View} from "angular2/core";

@Component({
   selector: 'my-app'
})

@View({
  template: '<h2>Hello World !!</h2>'
})

export class MyHelloWorldClass {

}
```

**Files Location:**

[image]

**Error:**

[image]

Comment: where is the port number after localhost in URL ?

Comment: XAMP does not need port no.

Comment: Does the import not require file extensions?

Comment: Can't say. This is my first program in A2.

Comment: In that case, change it to... `.import('hello_world_main.ts')`

Comment: `angular2/core-->@angular/core` and 
`angular2/platform/browser-->@angular/platform-browser-dynamic`

Comment: You're not using XAMP to serve your Angular2 app , do you ?

Comment: Yes, I am using XAMPP.

Comment: @Deadpool did you change your imports as i've mentioned ?

Comment: Perhaps adding `<head><base href="/ext">` might help